# Using parameter values to parse XML when using CROSS APPLY

Tags: xml-parsing

I have the following SQL to parse an XML data type stored in a table within SQL Server:

```
SELECT
   N.C.value('CustomerID[1]', 'int') value   
FROM dbo.t_xml_input
CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes('/Root/Customers') N(C);
```

I want to parameterise the node, value and definition variables so that I can use the same SQL within a cursor to extract different data items from the XML i.e. something like:

```
SELECT
   N.C.value('@para1', '@para2') value   
FROM dbo.t_xml_input
CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes('@para3') N(C);
```

The @para values will be stored in a table, which I will retrieve and loop through.

Is this at all possible and if so what is the correct syntax?

Thanks.